# MATLAB: extracting groups of columns into a submatrix?

Tags: matlab, extract, data-extraction, submatrix

I have a data-set, in which I want to extract columns 1-3, 7-9, 13-15, all the way to the end of the matrix

As an example, I've used the standard magic function to create a matrix

A=magic(10)

A =

```
92    99     1     8    15    67    74    51    58    40
98    80     7    14    16    73    55    57    64    41
 4    81    88    20    22    54    56    63    70    47
85    87    19    21     3    60    62    69    71    28
86    93    25     2     9    61    68    75    52    34
17    24    76    83    90    42    49    26    33    65
23     5    82    89    91    48    30    32    39    66
79     6    13    95    97    29    31    38    45    72
10    12    94    96    78    35    37    44    46    53
11    18   100    77    84    36    43    50    27    59
```

I know that I can extract single columns starting at 1, in intervals of 3 with the command:

Aex=a(:,1 : 3 : end)

Aex =

```
92     8    74    40
98    14    55    41
 4    20    56    47
85    21    62    28
86     2    68    34
17    83    49    65
23    89    30    66
79    95    31    72
10    96    37    53
11    77    43    59
```

Say I want to extract groups of columns instead (e.g. column 1-3, 7-9 etc.).

Is there a way to do this without having to manually point out all the column numbers?

Thanks for your help!
Rasmus

Answer (score 11):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
 Aex = A(:,[1:3 7:9])
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you would like the result all concatenated into another large matrix?

If that is the case, try this one on for size:

```ml
result = A(diag(0:2)*ones(3,floor((size(A,2) - 3)/6) + 1) + ...
            ones(3,floor((size(A,2) - 3)/6) + 1)*diag(1:6:(size(A,2)-3)))
```

That could probably be shortened with some matrix math rules. You could also parameterize the values so that it can be modified to do more than what this problem expects, (and also might make more sense),

```ml
a = 3;           
b = 6;          

result = A(diag(0:a-1)*ones(a,floor((size(A,2) - a)/b) + 1) + ...
            ones(a,floor((size(A,2) - a)/b) + 1)*diag(1:b:(size(A,2)-a)))
```

where `a` is the size of "group" (`length([1 2 3]) = length([7 8 9]) = ... = 3`), etc. and `b` is the column spacing (`[1...7...13...]` in your example)

If you would like them separated, I put them in cells here, but they can go to wherever you need:

```ml
a = 3;
b = 6;
results = {};
for Cols = 1:b:(size(A,2)-a)
    results{end+1} = A(:, Cols:(Cols+2));
end
```

I didn't check the speed of either of these, but I think the first one may be faster. You may want to split it up into terms so it's more readable, I just did it to fit on a single line (which isn't always the best way of writing code).

Comment: wtf ???????????? (so many question marks because of SO's limits on comment length)

Comment: I didn't say it was bad, but I would say that it is a very complicated way of doing something which has much simpler forms in Matlab.  Try as hard as I can, and I cannot see any merit in your proposed solution compared with my own effort.  I also observe that the SO community has yet to upvote your answer.  That's all.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I was just suggesting another way to parameterize the problem so that the solution is portable to other circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to do this:

```
M = magic(10);

n = size(M,2)
idx = sort([1:3:n 2:3:n 3:3:n])
M(:,idx)
```

---

If however, the pattern of removal is simpler than the pattern of colums that you want to keep you could use this instead:

```
A = magic(10);
B = A;
B(:,4:3:end)=[];
B(:,4:3:end)=[]; %Yes 3x the same line of code.
B(:,4:3:end)=[];
```